# RAID 1 configuration does not show after installation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp, hardware-raid, raid1, hp-smart-array

I used the HP Smart Array Configuration utility to setup a RAID 1 array (hardware P400 controller) using four disks. I created 2 logical drives with physical hard drive 2 mirroring drive 1 (o/s drives) and physical drive 4 mirroring 3. After upgrading to Windows Server 2008 R2, my RAID array is not visible under disk management (should it be?).

What is visible is drive c (Disk 0 - which are drives 1 & 2) listed as basic but with the capacity of just one drive. The other drive (Disk 1) also shows as basic with the capacity of a single drive but unallocated (it has no drive letter).

Both drives, however, show online leading me to believe that the RAID configuration is functioning somehow. Also, when I check the status with the Configuration disk, it shows that it's setup properly. Anyone have any ideas? How can I even access the unallocated drive for use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you created 2 logical disks, that's what you get in Disk Management. The P400 presents logical disks to Windows, not physical disks.

The health you see in Disk Management is the health of the logical volumes. That will not reflect, for example, a failure of one of the physical drives. You will need to monitor that using HP Array Configuration Utility software.

To use the unallocated drive, you need to create a volume on that drive. Right-click on the "Unallocated" and pick new volume.

Comment: I right-clicked and chose create simple volume. It now shows as a RAW volume that must be formatted to use. The drives were initially formatted in NTFS using the SmartArray Utility. I guess because they're presented as a single logical drive that Windows doesn't see this. If I reformat will I lose the hardware mirror?

Comment: Nothing you do in disk management can change your raid array configuration. So go ahead and format it as ntfs.